# How to get the Collage Formatter module to work?

Tags: media

I'm using the [Collage Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/collageformatter) module (Drupal 7) to create a gallery.

But I seem to have a problem when I apply the Collage Formatter image style. When the image is smaller the colorbox doesn't resize it and it leaves a white box. So I tried creating a new image style and apply it but it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?